# PowerPivot / DAX Parent Child Hierarchy function PATH Calculation Error

Tags: excel, hierarchy, powerpivot, dax

I'm looking into the Parent Child Hierarchy in PowerPivot/DAX. Below are some useful articles I have found.

[parent-child-hierarchies-in-tabular-with-denali](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2011/07/19/parent-child-hierarchies-in-tabular-with-denali.aspx)

[PowerPivot Denali: Parent child using DAX](http://www.kasperonbi.com/powerpivot-denali-parent-child-using-dax/)

[PATH Function (DAX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492167.aspx)

However, when I tried to implement the PATH function in DAX, I got the following error.

`=path(rptHierDate_rptHierDate[TREE_NODE_ID],rptHierDate_rptHierDate[PARENT_TREE_NODE_ID])`

[image: Error]

Below is a screenshot of my dataset. I have checked column TREE_NODE_ID has no duplication, and all values in column PARENT_TREE_NODE_ID exist in TREE_NODE_ID

[image]

I'm not sure why am I getting this error. Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure parent values exist in the tree column? Maybe they are the same at a glance but trailing/leading spaces could be causing the error.

Comment: Yes, I used the `MATCH` function in Excel to check the source data, and all parent_node_id have a match in the node_id